Routing to a playbook / Vertex AI Agent
i saw in a google training video can route a DialogFlow CX agent to a Vertex AI playbook (which I think is now called "agent" as well. The steps are:
From the Building an Agent module, go to Start Page
Select Routes
Go to Transitions and select playbooks.
However, when I go to my Routes menu and then to Transitions, I don't see a Playbooks option to select.
Any ideas?

Google rebrand Playbook as Vertex AI Agent Builder
You can create agentin Agent section and create playbook



